# Swift increment Int! not working

Tags: swift, increment, option-type

I understand how optionals work, but this is throwing me for a loop. I have a variable called `num` and I want to increment it, so I did the following:

```
var num:Int! = 0
num++             //ERROR - Unary operator ++ cannot be applied to an operand of type Int!
```

But for some reason Swift won't let me increment a force unwrapped `Int`, even though it is supposed to be treated like a regular `Int` with the capability for nil behind the scenes. So I tried the following, and it worked:

```
var num:Int! = 0
num = num + 1     //NO ERROR
```

However, based on the error message it gave me, I tried the following to make the increment operator still work:

```
var num:Int! = 0
num!++            //NO ERROR
```

My question is why does the first bit of code break, when the second and third bits of code don't? Also, since `num` is an `Int!`, shouldn't I be able to treat it like a regular `Int`? Lastly, since an `Int!` is supposed to be treated like a regular `Int`, how am I able to unwrap it in the third example? Thanks.

Comment: Since you are initializing it right away to `0`, it doesn't have to be optional. You can have `var num = 0` without a need for initializers

Comment: Thanks for the info, but regardless, why is my code above being weird?

Comment: @JackWu: Making it optional means you can set it to nil later if you have a reason to do so.

Comment: The postfix operator takes an "inout parameter", so this is essentially about the same problem: [Passing an implicitly unwrapped variable into inout parameter doesn't compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940308/passing-an-implicitly-unwrapped-variable-into-inout-parameter-doesnt-compile).

Comment: @gnasher729 I do know what an optional does. The question quite clearly expresses intention that `num` will never be set to `nil`.

Comment: @MartinR That makes sense, but does that mean that binary operators don't take inout parameters, since my second code block works? It seems kind of weird that unary operators can't use optionals, but binary operators can use them.

Comment: @Aderis: No, binary operators take two operands and return a result. It is `postfix func ++(inout x: Int) -> Int` vs `func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int`. – But I don't know *why* the automatic unwrapping does not happen with IUOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs with all `inout` parameters and should be considered a bug.

The usual way how `inout` parameters work is that their getter gets called once and their setter at least once. In this case the getter returns an `Int!`:

```
let num: Int! = 0
let num2 = num // is inferred to be of type Int!
```

so the signature of the getter/setter is not the same as the function/operator expects. But the compiler should implicitly unwrap the value if it gets assigned to an `Int` or passed like so:

```
var num3 = 0 // is of type Int
num3 = num // gets automatically unwrapped

// also with functions
func someFunc(i: Int) {}
someFunc(num) // gets automatically unwrapped
```

Sidenote:

Almost the same error occurs if you want to pass an `Int` to a function with an `inout` parameter of type `Int!`. But here it is obvious why this doesn't work (logically): The setter of an `Int` never takes a `nil`.

Answer (score -3):

You are using wrong type `Int!`, use `Int` instead

Comment: I am using it in a ViewController, which doesn't have an `init()` method, and all my initialization is being done in `viewDidLoad`, so it has to be some sort of optional, and don't want to make it an `Int?` because then I would have to deal with question marks everywhere, and it always has a value after my `viewDidLoad`

Comment: do the initialization in the declaration line `var num = 0`. `Int` is the default type

Comment: Thanks for the info, but regardless, why is my code with the optional being weird?

Comment: but your variable is initialized, why should you use optional? And `Int!` is not optional, `Int?` is optional. And in optional case `num!++` is correct way to increment this variable

Comment: This is not addressing the real issue here, i.e. "Why does `++` not work on `Int!`".