# Swift unary operator with implicitly unwrapped optional

Tags: swift, option-type, unary-operator, binary-operators

So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763467/swift-increment-int-not-working?noredirect=1#comment51460501_31763467), and it looks like the reason

```
var num:Int! = 0
num++
```

doesn't work is because the `++` operator takes an `inout` parameter, which implicitly unwrapped optionals are not. However, in

```
var num:Int! = 0
num = num + 1
```

the `+` operator works with the implicitly unwrapped optional, meaning that the binary operator *doesn't* require an `inout` parameter. So my question is, why do unary and binary operators have different parameter requirements? It seems kind of silly to me to be able to use an `Int!` with only binary operators, but use an `Int` with everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why do unary and binary operators have different parameter
>   requirements?

Well, it isn't a unary vs. binary question.  There are unary operators that work with `Int!`.  For instance:

```
var i: Int! = 17
var j = -i
```

`-` is a unary operator and it works.  The question comes back to the issue of `inout`.  The `++` prefix and postfix operators for `Int` don't work with `Int!` because the variable is passed as `inout` (since `++` modifies the original variable in addition to returning a value). `inout` requires the type to exactly match.

Note that implicitly unwrapped optionals are still optionals.

```
var i: Int! = 17
var k = i    // k has the type Int!
var m = i!   // m has the type Int
```

So passing an implicitly unwrapped optional as an `inout` variable that requires the non-optional type doesn't work because `inout` variables need to exactly match the type expected and `Int` and `Int!` are two very different types.  The variable must either be explicitly unwrapped, or you need to provide an overloaded function that takes the optional type.

You might ask, why doesn't Swift just unwrap the `Int!` for you and call `++` with the `Int`?  Well, `++` both modifies the variable and returns a value.  If Swift unwrapped the `Int!` and called `++` with an `Int`, then the type of the return would be `Int`.  Then you'd have people on StackOverflow asking, "why does `var i: Int! = 17; var j = i++` make `j` an `Int` instead of an `Int!` ?".  To do it right, `++` needs to return an `Int` when it is given an `Int`, and return an `Int!` when it is given an `Int!`.  So, what is needed in an overloaded function.

It is possible to overload `++` and make `++` prefix and postfix functions for `Int!`:

```
prefix func ++(inout x: Int!) -> Int! {
    return ++x!
}

postfix func ++(inout x: Int!) -> Int! {
    return x!++
}

var i: Int! = 17
var j = ++i
print("i = \(i), j = \(j)")  // "i = 18, j = 18"
j = i++
print("i = \(i), j = \(j)")  // "i = 19, j = 18"
```

As to why the Swift designers haven't done this, only they know why.

Comment: `x++` is much faster than `x = x + 1`, which might be why they haven't implemented it in the way you provided. Also `x!++` works instead of `x++`, I am just wondering why the language doesn't auto-unwrap the optional for you when the variable is implicitly unwrapped.

Comment: They can implement however they want.  I just wanted to show that it is possible to eliminate the thought that **it can't be done**.

Comment: There, got rid of the `x = x + 1` which wasn't returning the right result for postfix anyway.

Comment: An `inout` variable type must match exactly. `Int!` and `Int` are two very different types.  If they wanted to support `++` with `Int!`, they would likely do something like I have defined above.

Comment: But why do they even need the `inout` keyword in the first place if it makes it so restrictive? Can't they just do something like `postfix func ++(x:Int) -> Int {return x++}` and be done, that way the unwrapping happens when the parameter is passed and everything works?

Comment: You need `inout` because the `++` function modifies the original variable in addition to returning a value.

Comment: Note, `var i: Int! = 17; var j = -i` works and `-` is a unary operator.  Some unary operators work with implicitly unwrapped optionals.  In this case, `-` doesn't modify the original variable, so `inout` isn't needed.